# Visual Studio C# grammar/sentence structure-checking method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parsing

I'm working with *C#* in *Visual Studio*. I need an object to which I can send a String containing an English sentence. I need the object to have a method that will tell me if my English sentence has any `grammar/structure errors`.

Think of the spell/grammar checker in MS Word. Any `grammar/structure errors` will be underlined by a green line. I need to determine if any arbitrary sentence would have a green underline if it were written in MS Word.

If such a thing exists it may look like this:

```
checkGrammar("Arbitrary sentence");   //returns true/false based on being      correct or not.
```

I have looked for something like this but all my search efforts are dominated by results for a **Visual Studio Spell Checker** which checks your actual code....not what I need.

Does anyone know if such a thing exists in C#?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Visual Studio isn't a programming language, try "C# Spell Checker" https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20spell%20checker

Comment: The linked "duplicate" is NOT a duplicate of this question. it only deals with spellcheck and is specific to winforms.

Comment: @BradleyUffner The OP states `would have a green underline`, which sounds like they're using WinForms or WPF, and one of the answers to the duplicate target detail how to use these functions elsewhere (e.g, WPF).

Comment: @AStopher, it's still NOT a duplicate, as it only mentions spelling and this is specific to spelling AND grammar.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Really not sure why you're pinging me about a comment I wrote almost five years ago, but one of the answers on the duplicate target _did_ detail (or still does, I haven't checked) how to use those functions elsewhere. I never implied the question was a duplicate, simply that one of the answers in the duplicate target might be helpful.

Comment: @AStopher Ahh, apologies, I wasn't looking at the dates.

Answer (score 6):

You may be able to use Word's Grammar checker grammatically if you can be sure it will be installed on the computer running the program.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.checkgrammar.aspx)

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

return word.CheckGrammar("String to check");
```